# Uploadify - Passing Information Back to The Original Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, uploadify

I have an Send.aspx page that has an uploadify control on it.  Upload.ashx handles the file upload.

I am adding a file record to a sql database in the Upload.ashx file and I need to get the ID of that record back from Upload.aspx when it is done.

Can't get it working with Sessions. =(  Something to do with an Adobe bug?

What would the best way to handle this be?

Here is the uploadify control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                // <![CDATA[
                var contestID = $('[id$=HiddenFieldContestID]').val();
                var maxEntries = $('[id$=HiddenFieldMaxEntries]').val();
                var userID = $('[id$=HiddenFieldUserID]').val();
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#fileInput').uploadify({
                        'uploader': '../uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                        'script': '../uploadify/Upload.ashx',
                        'scriptData': { 'contestID': contestID, 'maxEntries': maxEntries, 'userID': userID },
                        'cancelImg': '../uploadify/cancel.png',
                        'auto': true,
                        'multi': false,
                        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.jpeg',
                        'queueSizeLimit': 1,
                        'sizeLimit': 4000000,
                        'buttonText': 'Choose Image',
                        'folder': '/uploads',
                        'onAllComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                            document.getElementById('<%= ButtonCleanup.ClientID %>').click();
                        }

                    });
                });
                // ]]></script>
```

This took a while for me to figure out.  But in retrospect it is extremely simple.  For this reason, I mad a video tutorial to help newcomers get started quickly and understand how this awesome control works.

**Video Tutorial from start to finish:**

http://casonclagg.com/articles/6/video-tutorial-uploadify-asp-net-c-sharp.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in my own script that I'm using an `onComplete` event instead of `onAllComplete`. Unless a config option escapes me, `onComplete`  will trigger after each Upload.aspx call (the files are uploaded individually - again maybe this is configurable). According to the documentation, `onAllComplete` doesn't actually pass back request data (which makes sense because it's done outside of the scope of the individual uploads).

Anything that Upload.aspx outputs should appear in the `response` parameter. You can simply have it output the id of the element the script created and the response should contain the appropriate string.

Comment: I thought it broke the swf's functionality if it didn't return a 0 or 1 after each upload....Not sure why I thought that....Well, isn't that nice.  =D Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As promised, I made a video tutorial on how to use an Uploadify control in an ASP.Net application.

http://casonclagg.com/articles/6/video-tutorial-uploadify-asp-net-c-sharp.aspx

Hope this helps.

**The short answer to my questions is this:**

When you return `context.Response.Write("foo");` out of your Upload.ashx handler...

And put this in your uploadify control:

```
 'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
    alert(response);
 }
```

An alert box with the word foo will pop up.

**You can make this something more complicated** like

`context.Response.Write("id=55&title=This is the title");`

and parse the values out yourself in your `OnComplete` or `OnAllComplete` in JQuery.